# Is it possible to use GPT-4 32K directly from OpenAI?

Tags: chatgpt, gpt, openai

I use GPT-4-32K on poe.com.

On poe.com, the use of GPT-4-32K is very restricted.

Is it possible to use GPT-4-32K directly from OpenAI as an individual user?

Answer (score 0):

As of March 4, 2024 it looks that the access to any OpenAI GPT-4  model including `gpt-4-32` are only available to paid users.

P.S. According to the OpenAI docs, `gpt-4-32` points to `gpt-4-32k-0613`. See the linked resources in the **Resources** section of this answer.

---

Besides https://chat.openai.com, aka ChatGPT, OpenAI has other "web apps" like the API playground -> https://platform.openai.com/playground.

As of March 4, 2024, ChatGPT (https://chat.openai.com) shows a button inviting users on the free plan to upgrade to get access to GPT-4.

[image: ChatGPT upgrade plan]

Clicking the above button ChatGPT shows the following modal dialog about the plans:

[image: ChatGPT plans]

Please note that GPT-4 is available for paid plans only.

The OpenAI Platform Playground has a dropdown with three options

- Assistants [Beta]
- Chat
- Complete [Legacy]

A dropdown to select the model to be used is shown when selecting Chat. In my case, the dropdown options don't include GPT-4.

[image: Playground > Chat > Model dropdown extended]

### Reference

- [GPT-4](https://openai.com/research/gpt-4)

### Resources

- [Models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models)

Comment: Are you talking about ***GPT-4*** or ***GPT-4-32K***?   Those are two different apps on `poe.com`.

Comment: I'm talking about GPT-4 as a family of models, not a specific model. Please check out the poe.com documentation to learn what specific model uses their **GPT-4** "thing".